# Why Julia gives error on very simple code?

Tags: julia

I have a very simple Julia code:

```
x=0
for n in 1:10
    x = x + n
end
println(x)
```

And it gives me an error:

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: x not defined

Stacktrace:

[1] top-level scope at /home/piotr/julia_codes/t4.jl:3

[2] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377

[3] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:288

[4] _start() at ./client.jl:484

in expression starting at /home/piotr/julia_codes/t4.jl:2

What should I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Julia 1.6.0 has changed how scoping mechanism within REPL so now this works
2. Basically your goal is to have the code in functions rather than "naked"
3. Version independent code could look like this (or you could use `global` as in the other answer):

```
let x=0
    for n in 1:10
        x = x + n
    end
    println(x)
end
```

Comment: The reason why I accepted your answer is 2nd statement, it works in function:

`
function get_sum(n)
    x=0
    for i in 1:n
        x+=i
        println(i)
    end
    return x
end

println(get_sum(10))
`

Comment: There was a huge discussion on how scoping should behave outside of functions (lots of it on forums). Basically if you want efficient code that does something keep it in functions. Functions define their own scope and then the behavior is "normal"

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
x=0
for n in 1:10
    global x
    x = x + n
end
println(x)
```

This is related to the scope in JuliaLang.

For more info refer to [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/x-not-defined-error-even-though-it-is/20714) JuliaLang discussion.

Comment: Thank you, it was code from tutorial: https://github.com/JuliaAcademy/JuliaTutorials/blob/main/introductory-tutorials/intro-to-julia/04.%20Loops.ipynb

Comment: Tutorial runs in Jupyter notebook that as of Julia 1.5.0 had different scoping rules than Julia REPL.